# Display ajax response value in table

Tags: javascript, html, sql, ajax

I want to display  sql query result on a table during ajax call.I wrote the code which executes the query during ajax call but when i tried to display these values in table it displays null value on the div tag.What is the reason?How can i display the result set value in table format.

Mycode:

ViewQuery.jsp

```
<%-- 
    Document   : ViewQuery
    Created on : Nov 10, 2014, 10:23:48 AM
    Author     : user
--%>

<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="querywork.ReadXml"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="querywork.DBConnection"%>
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Zerotype Website Template</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
                <script lang="javascript">
                    try
                    {

                        var request;


                        function myfunction(str)
                        {
                            try
                            {


                                var url="queryview.jsp"
                                url=url+"?query="+str  
                                url=url+"&sid="+Math.random()

                                if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                                    request=new XMLHttpRequest();
                                }
                                else if(window.ActiveXObject){
                                    request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                                }

                                try
                                {
                                    request.onreadystatechange=getInfo;
                                    request.open("GET",url,true);
                                    request.send();
                                }
                                catch(e)
                                {
                                    alert("Unable to connect to server");
                                }

                                //     alert(textboxes2)
                                //        alert(select)
                            }
                            catch(err)
                            {
                                alert(err)
                            }
                        }
                        function getInfo(){
                            if(request.readyState==4){
                                var val=request.responseText;
                                document.getElementById('amit').innerHTML=val;
                            }
                        }





                    }
                    catch(err)
                    {}

                </script>
                </head>
                <body>

                </body>
                <body>
                    <form method="POST" action="ViewQuery.jsp">
                        <%

                            ReadXml rxml = new ReadXml();
                            ArrayList al = rxml.readXML(0);
                        %>


                        <font color="white">   Choose query</font></label>
                        </label>

                        <select id="c" name="Chooser" style="width:800px; height:50px" onchange="myfunction(this.value)">
                            <% for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
%><option><font color="white"><%=al.get(i)%></font></option>
                            <% }%>
                        </select>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>


                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p><font color="white">  Result:</font>  <font color="white">   <div id="amit"> </div></font></p>

                    </form>


                </body>
                </html>
```

queryview.jsp

```
    <%-- 
        Document   : queryview
        Created on : Nov 16, 2014, 7:15:09 PM
        Author     : user
    --%>
    <%@page import="querywork.getObject"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.DatabaseMetaData"%>
    <%@page import="querywork.Query"%>
    <%@page import="querywork.Parser"%>
    <%@page import="gudusoft.gsqlparser.EDbVendor"%>
    <%@page import="querywork.gettablecolumns"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>

    <%@page import="querywork.DBConnection"%>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>

            <%

                String responseText = new String("");
                boolean flg = false;
                String query1 = (String) request.getParameter("query");
    String[] colname=new String[100];
                EDbVendor dbVendor = EDbVendor.dbvmysql;
                try {

                    getObject g = new getObject(dbVendor);

                    Parser parser1 = new Parser();
                    Parser.Node parsedNode1 = parser1.parse(query1);
                    g.setSqltext(query1);
                    System.out.println(query1);

                    String table = g.run();

                    String[] splitstring = table.split("Columns:");

                    String newval = splitstring[1].replaceAll("\\([^\\)]*\\)", "");

                    String[] inputSplitNewLine = newval.split("\\\n");

    int i1=0;

                    String[] firstval = splitstring[0].split("\\\n");
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/", "root", "");
                    DatabaseMetaData dbmd = conn.getMetaData();
                    responseText= "<table border=1 cellpadding =2 cellspacing=3><tr>";
                    for(int p=0;p<inputSplitNewLine.length;p++)
                                           {
                        String col=inputSplitNewLine[p];

    responseText=responseText+"  <td> "+col+" </td>";
                    }
                    responseText="</tr>";
                    ResultSet ctlgs = dbmd.getCatalogs();
                    for (int i = 1; i < firstval.length; i++) {
                        while (ctlgs.next()) {


                            String dbname = ctlgs.getString(1);

                            DBConnection dbc = new DBConnection(dbname);
                            ResultSet rs = dbc.SelectTable();
                            while (rs.next()) {
                                String columnName = "";
                                String tableName = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
                                if (tableName.equalsIgnoreCase(firstval[i])) {
                                    DBConnection dbc1 = new DBConnection(dbname);
                                    ResultSet rs1 = dbc1.execute(query1);

                                    while(rs1.next()) {
                                        out.println(rs1.getString(1));
                                         responseText=responseText +"<tr><td> "+rs1.getString(1)+"</td></tr>";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    out.print(responseText);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    out.print(e);
                }

            %>
        </head>
        <body>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether getting data is null or not.
before printing data into table cell put condition for verification whether fetch data is valid or not or not null, null value add space in cell.

Example code:-

```
while(rs.next())
{
    %>
     <tr>
    <td><%= (rs.getString(1) !='')?rs.getString(1):"-" %></td> 
    <td><%= (rs.getString(2) !='')?rs.getString(2):"-" %></td> 
    <%  
}
```

Your code :- write only following code

```
        <%-- 
                Document   : queryview
                Created on : Nov 16, 2014, 7:15:09 PM
                Author     : user
            --%>
            <%@page import="querywork.getObject"%>
            <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
            <%@page import="java.sql.DatabaseMetaData"%>
            <%@page import="querywork.Query"%>
            <%@page import="querywork.Parser"%>
            <%@page import="gudusoft.gsqlparser.EDbVendor"%>
            <%@page import="querywork.gettablecolumns"%>
            <%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
            <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
            <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>

            <%@page import="querywork.DBConnection"%>
            <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

                    <%

                        String responseText = new String("");
                        boolean flg = false;
                        String query1 = (String) request.getParameter("query");
            String[] colname=new String[100];
                        EDbVendor dbVendor = EDbVendor.dbvmysql;
                        try {

                            getObject g = new getObject(dbVendor);

                            Parser parser1 = new Parser();
                            Parser.Node parsedNode1 = parser1.parse(query1);
                            g.setSqltext(query1);
                            System.out.println(query1);

                            String table = g.run();

                            String[] splitstring = table.split("Columns:");

                            String newval = splitstring[1].replaceAll("\\([^\\)]*\\)", "");

                            String[] inputSplitNewLine = newval.split("\\\n");

            int i1=0;

                            String[] firstval = splitstring[0].split("\\\n");
                            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/", "root", "");
                            DatabaseMetaData dbmd = conn.getMetaData();
                            responseText= "<table border=1 cellpadding =2 cellspacing=3><tr>";
                            for(int p=0;p<inputSplitNewLine.length;p++)
                                                   {
                                String col=inputSplitNewLine[p];

            responseText=responseText+"  <td> "+col+" </td>";
                            }
                            responseText="</tr>";
                            ResultSet ctlgs = dbmd.getCatalogs();
                            for (int i = 1; i < firstval.length; i++) {
                                while (ctlgs.next()) {


                                    String dbname = ctlgs.getString(1);

                                    DBConnection dbc = new DBConnection(dbname);
                                    ResultSet rs = dbc.SelectTable();
                                    while (rs.next()) {
                                        String columnName = "";
                                        String tableName = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
                                        if (tableName.equalsIgnoreCase(firstval[i])) {
                                            DBConnection dbc1 = new DBConnection(dbname);
                                            ResultSet rs1 = dbc1.execute(query1);

                                            while(rs1.next()) {
                                                out.println(rs1.getString(1));
                                                 responseText=responseText +"<tr><td> "+rs1.getString(1)+"</td></tr>";
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            out.print(responseText);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            out.print(e);
                        }

                    %>
```

Comment: I solved the issue.The problem is with my css.I my css table border is set as 0 that is why this problem occured.Anyway thank you for your kind cooperation